# Cannot access before initialization - Angular NGXS

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I am using Angular application with state management as NGXS, I have used a selector to get data from the store, in which I have used the reference of other state to get data based on conditions.

In local, the below code is working fine, but I am facing the following error on the server. Can anybody please check and help?

**Note** - Both the *ConfigurationState* and *ViewState* are imported in the same module in root.

## Facing error in below code

```
@Selector([ConfigurationState])
  static viewItems(state: IViewState, configurationState: IConfigurationState) {
    let filterState = state.views.filter(
      x => x.pageCode === configurationState.currentState.currentPageCode
    );
    return filterState.map(e => {
      return { name: e.name, id: e.id, isDefault: e.isDefault };
    });
  }
```

## Error Facing

[Error Facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9wkP.png)

Comment: A bit late to the party but I had a similar issue and it was caused by a circular reference in my selectors. Make sure that if ConfigurationState imports something from ViewState that ViewState doesnt' import from ConfigurationState and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this.

```
@Selector([forwardRef(() => ConfigurationState)])
```

updated

"configrationState" was undefined. so I used a dynamic selector.

```
static viewItems() {
    return createSelector([ViewState, ConfigurationState], (state: IViewState, configurationState: IConfigurationState) => {
        return {};
    });
}
```